# Find min number by higher order functions using php

Tags: php, higher-order-functions, minimax

I'm trying to find the minimum number in array but it doesn't return the min value,
it just works for the maximum number.

code:

```
function maxNumber($acc, $val) {

    return $acc > $val ? $acc : $val;

}

function minNumber($acc, $val) {

    return $acc < $val ? $acc : $val;

}

$nums = [5, 12, 1, 50, 2, 180, 90, 45];

echo array_reduce($nums, "maxNumber");
echo "</br>";
echo array_reduce($nums, "minNumber");
```

The result should be:
180
1

but the output is 180

Can you Explain why ?!

Answer (score 2):

##### explanation for your code

You must first check for null before setting the min value if it is smaller.

```php
<?php
function maxNumber($acc, $val) {
    return $acc > $val ? $acc : $val;
}

function minNumber($min, $val) {
    if ((is_numeric($min) && $val < $min) || $min == null) {
        $min = $val;
    }
    return $min;    
}

$nums = [5, 12, 1, 50, 2, 180, 90, 45];

echo array_reduce($nums, "maxNumber");
echo "</br>";
echo array_reduce($nums, "minNumber", 0);
```

#### but

You can use the `min()` and `max()` function for that:

```php
$nums = [5, 12, 1, 50, 2, 180, 90, 45];
echo min($nums);
echo '#';
echo max($nums);
// output: 1 # 180
```

min(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

max(): https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.max.php